# returning pointer to a character array from a function in a different file other than main

Tags: c

I can't return a pointer to a character array from a different file other than the main function. It always says "segmentation fault". But if I write the function in the same file as main, There is no problem.

```
/* this is in mainfunc.c file*/
int main()
{


    char ch[5]={'a','b','c','d','\0'};
    char *res=retchararray(ch);
    printf("%s\n",res);/*I get segmentation fault only when I use this printf*/

}

/* this function is in other file newfile.c */

char *retchararray( char *p){

    char *str;
    str=p;
    unsigned int len=strlen(p);

    *(str+len)='e';
    *(str+len+1)='\0';

    return str;

}
```

I use netbeans on Mac OS to do C Programming.

Can some please tell me what is the problem? Or Am I doing some mistake here?

Comment: I would change `char ch[5]` to `char ch[6]` to accommodate the extra 'e' character.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function retchararray overflows your array. You use more memory than you have reserved.
This happens in `*(str+len+1) = '\0'` and causes the segfault.

Comment: Yeah I agree that. But, It works fine when retchararray function is in the same file as main.

Comment: @Loki: This is undefined behaviour and you are just lucky when it works.

Comment: @Blagovest Buyukliev: Yeah may be. Because I have been trying a lot. I don't understand what is happening.